# onreadystatechane function not firing

Tags: javascript, xml, text-files

I'm updating some old code written in 2017. While debugging it looks like the problem boils down to this fuction:

```
    let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open('GET', file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( rawFile.readyState === 4 ) {
            if ( rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0 ) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Where the function called in `onreadystatechange` never runs.
I've seen similar questions, but no answers that seem to resolve the problem I'm having.
Keep in mind that this used to run flawlessly 2017-2019.

Comment: What is `file`?

Comment: @Kosh A regular .txt file with words seperated by linebreaks

Comment: @Kosh Oh, that's a string with the name of whatever file I want to read.

Comment: @Kosh One example would be "sv.txt".

Comment: It should be URL, not just a filename. You may read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @Kosh It's the path to the file since it's located in the same folder. It has always worked before.

Comment: If you look in console, you may see that it's translated to URL when requested. What is that URL? Your code is correct, I'm just trying to get more details to understand the issue better.

Comment: @Kosh Well it still just says "sv.txt" in the console. But I also found this while looking at the properties of `rawFile`. `onreadystatechange: null`